# @JoinTable with inherited tables

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I have the following problem. An **employee** can belong to multiple **organizations** and vice versa. So it is a many-to-many relation. As you can see the list of organizations is joined by the table **OrganizationMember**. The problem is that  **OrganizationMember** is inherited from **Member** which contains **employee_id** and **organization_id** is in **OrganizationMember**. Hibernate generates SQL query which tries to take **employee_id** from **OrganizationMember**, not **Member**, which causes an error.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
   private Long id;

    //...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
           name = "OrganizationMember",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", 
           referencedColumnName = "id", table = "Member"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", 
           referencedColumnName = "id", table ="OrganizationMember")
     )
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Organization> organizationMemberList;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "OrganizationMember")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@DiscriminatorValue("ORGANIZATION_MEMBER")
public class OrganizationMember extends Member {
   //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Member")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Member implements Serializable {
     //...
}
```

**The error:**
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'employee_id'.

Comment: A join table is not mapped to an Entity. It is a join table and nothing more, with no Java representation (other than the ids of the objects, and the List). You have a relation between `Employee` and `Organization`. Those are the only entities here. The rest is simply wrong

Comment: @BillyFrost, I know how ugly it is. The problem is that I am dealing with the existing code which already contains this. I can't just remove it, because it is used in some other places in the code.

Comment: @BillyFrost, so the question was is there any way to deal with the **@JoinTable** annotation provided we have two tables, a parent one and a child one, instead of a single join table.

Comment: You make the `Member` an entity, and have the relation to `Member` of course. And then `Member` has to have a relation to `Organization`. aka object oriented programming